# Magento; change how customer login

Tags: magento, authentication

I need to add an alternative verfification in the login.

The clients can login normally with their email, as always, and i want that their can login with a number provided by me.

I only find 'customer_login' observer, but it doesn't works.

```
<events>
    <customer_login>
        <observers>
            <login_with_external_id>
                <class>module/observer</class>
                <method>loginWithExternalId</method>
            </login_with_external_id>
        </observers>
    </customer_login>
```

How can i do?, any idea?

Thanks for any help

Comment: like OTP during login?

Comment: whats OTP mean?

Comment: like a one time password for an extra layer of security

Comment: For example yes. But it's permanent. The login must accept the email or the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found an answer:

```
<controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginpost>
```

This works for me